# XSLT 1.0 a potential number of replacements with REPLACE method produce a StackOverFlow Exception

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I try to convert an XML file to Json format using XSLT version 1.0, I'm on the case where I have a potential number of replacements using a Replace method on XSL. This produce an StackOverFlowException.

The Replace method is called recursively, so I had this problem. Is there any solution to solve this?

```
    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use?

Comment: I don't use any XSLT 1.0 special processor, I'm newbie using XSLT

Comment: Run http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest2.xml through your processor and tell us the results. Or move on to XSLT 2.0 as provided by Saxon 9, Altova or XmlPrime.

Comment: Could you provide a sample XML for which this behaviour occurs? And also the way the template is originally called (to figure out what you pass into the parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use libxslt, you can make use of the EXSLT `str:replace` function instead of a recursive template, i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="str">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="str:replace(., '&quot;', '\&quot;')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms `<data>This is a text with "quoted" parts</data>` into `<data>This is a text with \"quoted\" parts</data>`.

As an alternative, `xsltproc`, the command line tool using libxslt, has a setting `--maxdepth val : increase the maximum depth (default 3000)` you might want to increase/change if you need more recursive depth I think.

Comment: I'm using libxml with c++ can you tell me please how exactly I can increase the maxdepth value, THANKS

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with details of the C API of libxslt, someone else needs to help with that.

Comment: I looked at the source of `xsltproc` and in https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxslt/tree/xsltproc/xsltproc.c?h=v1.1.28#n476 it sets the `ctxt->maxTemplateDepth` of an `xsltTransformContextPtr`.